# Find the row/column of the $n^\text{th}$ word in a list of words arranged in a grid

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Here is a list of twelve words arranged in a grid with four rows and three words per row

```
alpha   betta    gamma
one     two      three
better  faster   stronger
major   captain  colonel
```

How can I find out which row and column the $11^\text{th}$  word, the word "*captain*", is in? Like, knowing that it's the $11^\text{th}$  word, how can I tell mathematically that it's the second word in the forth row? Or similarly how can I tell the position of the word "*better*" knowing only that it's the $7^\text{th}$ word in the list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer this, you need to be familiar with [modular arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic) and the [floor function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions).

If your grid has $m$ words per row, then the $k^{\text{th}}$ word will be the $(k \bmod m)^{\text{th}}$ word in the $(\lfloor (k-1)/m \rfloor +1)^{\text{th}}$ row. I think the best way to realize *why* these formulas work is to try them on a few example words, so for a few specific cases of $k$, and see what happens. A quick point though, the $+1$ and $-1$ in the formula for the row only need to be there because we are indexing our rows and columns starting at $1$ instead of $0$ (i.e. in the above grid we're saying that the word *alpha* is the first word of the first row, and not the zeroth word of the zeroth row).

Comment: $(k \bmod m)$ is the remainder when $k$ is divided by $m$. You can't really "replace" it. Instead, learn to love it.